# A question about matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that${\left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\|_2} = \mathop {\max {{\left\| {Ax} \right\|}_2}}\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} $.Let $A$ is Hermitian and $A \in {M_n}(C)$.Is this true that ${\left\| {\left| A \right|} \right\|_2} = \mathop {\max \left| {(Ax,x)} \right|}\limits_{{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1} $?

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is Hermitian, the eigenvalues are real and there is a unitary $U$ such that $\Lambda = U^*AU$ is diagonal.

Let $l = \max_k |\lambda_k|$, where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues.

Then $\|Ax\|^2 = \| U \Lambda U^*x\|^2= \| \Lambda U^*x\|^2 = \sum_k |\lambda_k [U^*x]_k|^2 \le l^2 \sum_k |[U^*x]_k|^2 = l^2$, so we see
that $\|A\| \le l$. Since we can take $x$ to be an eigenvalue corresponding to $l$, we see that $\|A\| = l$.

We see that $|\langle Ax, x \rangle | \le \|A\|$, for $\|x\| \le 1$, and if we choose $x$ to be a unit eigenvector corresponding to $l$, we have
$|\langle Ax, x \rangle | =l$